# Check if given input is a valid IP or Hostname or something invalid

Tags: python, python-3.x, validation, networking, network-programming

I am trying to create a program to check whether the given input is a valid hostname, valid IP, or neither.
The program is able to recognize a valid hostname or IP.  However, If I try to put something random, like "xyz", it doesn't print the error message I want.

```
import socket
if __name__ == '__main__':
    hostname = 'hyuiolpp'
    if socket.gethostbyname(hostname) == hostname:
        print('{} is a valid IP address'.format(hostname))
    elif socket.gethostbyname(hostname) != hostname:
        print('{} is a valid hostname'.format(hostname))
    else:
        print("Something is wrong")
```

The error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".....", line 5, in <module>
    if socket.gethostbyname(hostname) == hostname:
socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add a simple `try` block and catch the error(s) generated.

```
import socket

def main():
    hostname = 'hyuiolpp'
    try:
        if socket.gethostbyname(hostname) == hostname:
            print('{} is a valid IP address'.format(hostname))
        elif socket.gethostbyname(hostname) != hostname:
            print('{} is a valid hostname'.format(hostname))
    except socket.gaierror:
        print("Something is wrong")

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Few Things:

1.) I added a `main()` function and just called it in your `__main__` check as it seems to be a better practice.  I don't think there's anything wrong with yours, but from my experiences most people code this way, probably because it's easier to comment out one `#main()` than dozens of lines during debug or even to test out different functions locally.

2.) You'll probably want to handle each error raised differently.  During your unit testing you'll find out what other errors (beside socket.gaierror) are raised and what errors you might anticipate, and figure out how your program is supposed to handle those scenarios.  You can add extra `except`s for each error (or group them together if the group is handled one way).  Using just `except:` to catch all is generally considered a bad practice unless you're okay with that.

Answer (score 1):

Use a try-except block.  The problem is that `xyz` causes a run-time fault in `gethostbyname` -- instead of a `False` value, the program turns over to the error handler.  Something like

```
try: 
    sock = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)
    if sock == ...
except:
    print("Something is wrong")
```

Comment: Using a bare except?

Comment: Just for illustration, and because I haven't researched the returned errors.  Bare except is not good practice.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I think you have a concept problem:

> check whether the given input is a valid Hostname or valid IP or none of them either

You can check if the IP is valid using the RFCs for IPv4 and IPv6 but you can never discard a hostname because `xyz` can be reachable within you LAN and not from the internet.

Also I don't know python very well but it seems that your code is generating an exception that must be caught with a try-catch block.